# How to ignore some errors or warnings in PHP_CodeSniffer

Tags: php

I'm using PHP_CodeSniffer to analyse my php code. The problem is that the code of my applications is quite complex (about 10,000 files) and it is a bit old (about 15 years) so it follows no standards like PSR.
That's the reason why CodeSniffer produces very large reports. Because it takes too much time to fix all "problems", I'm thinking about to ignore some things, f.e.

```
Class name must begin with a capital letter
```

or

```
Opening brace of a class must be on the line after the definition
```

Is there a way to tell CodeSniffer to ignore such errors when creating the report?

Answer (score 4):

To disable/re-enable entire coding standard or specific sniffs for just a given fragment of code - use some special comments

```
// phpcs:disable Generic.Commenting.Todo.Found
$xmlPackage = new XMLPackage;
$xmlPackage['error_code'] = get_default_error_code_value();
// TODO: Add an error message here.
$xmlPackage->send();
// phpcs:enable
```

or

```
// phpcs:disable PEAR,Squiz.Arrays
$foo = [1,2,3];
bar($foo,true);
// phpcs:enable PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature
bar($foo,false);
// phpcs:enable
```

Note: All `phpcs:disable` and `phpcs:enable` comments only apply to the file they are contained within. After the file has finished processing all sniffs are re-enabled for future files.

You can also ignore a single line using the `phpcs:ignore` comment. This comment will ignore the line that the comment is on, and the following line.

```
// phpcs:ignore
$foo = [1,2,3];
bar($foo, false);

// phpcs:ignore Squiz.Arrays.ArrayDeclaration.SingleLineNotAllowed
$foo = [1,2,3];
bar($foo, false);
```

If you want to only check your files for a small list of sniffs you can specify them on the command line

```
$ phpcs --standard=PEAR --sniffs=Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant,PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent /path/to/code
```

Or you can run the whole coding standard and exclude a small list of sniffs

```
$ phpcs --standard=PEAR --exclude=Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant,PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent /path/to/code
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own ruleset. 
Here's info on available options: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml  and here you can find how to create such: https://ncona.com/2012/12/creating-your-own-phpcs-standard/

You can copy existing one (like PSR2) and adjust it to your needs.

On github of codesniffer project you can find PSR2 ruleset: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/PSR2/ruleset.xml

Answer (score 1):

Because I have a large nubmer of files and probably some excludes, it seems a good idea to define my own ruleset. I followed the instructions under the linked pages and created this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyRuleset">
    <description>Coding standard based on Zend with some additions.</description>

    <!-- Include the whole Zend standard -->
    <rule ref="Zend"/>

    <!-- Exclude some rules -->
    <rule ref="Generic.Classes.OpeningBraceSameLine">
        <exclude name="Generic.Classes.OpeningBraceSameLine"/>
    </rule>

</ruleset>
```

I start the analyze process with:

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=/path/to/my/ruleset.xml /path/to/my/app
```

The process was completed successfully but I still get the error:

```
Opening brace of a class must be on the line after the definition
```

And the class definition in my php file looks like this:

```
class MyTool {
}
```